# Android: Network calls stacking with LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle

I have the following problem:

- I have to make 2 network calls, one is a quick one and is important to be displayed as fast as possible and the other one is a lot slower, but it doesn't matter if it's slower. Both network calls' result end up in the same list of objects (size is about  50), which are displayed in a recycler view.
  -In order to make the second call, the first one needs to be complete.

I currently have a method that does the first network call and when we get the result from it, it does liveData.postValue(result) and starts making the second, using the same result. However, the fragment observes the first change properly, then observes the second change properly, but the list inside the recycler view gets somehow updated inbetween those 2 times observing. What ends up happening is, the list inside of the recycler view is already updated before the LiveData gets observed, therefore the DiffUtil compares the two lists, finds them completely identical and does not push the update.

So far I've tried:

- Calling .await , .invokeOnCompletion type of functions on the first network call
- Tried using delay before starting the second function
- I tried updating the LiveData both on each successful element update and only when the whole list of 50ish items are updated

I looked into Transformations, but I don't see how they would help me as they are pushing updates to a different LiveData object and I would get in an infinite loop if I was calling the update function each time the data changes. I guess I could just have two different LiveData objects and have them update the same recycler view when observed, but that would also mean that the second function would have to be waited out to finish and that may take over 20 seconds or maybe even 1 minute in some cases, so it would be a lot better if the data gets updated slowly as the user scrolls down.

Anyway, I am quite lost, I don't know what more to Google and what more to look up, after being stuck for a couple of days on this now, so any guidance would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How can the first list possibly be updated with content that comes later and is put into a different list? Are you sure you aren't using a single mutable list and passing the same instance the second time? I would make sure you're just using `read-only` Lists to ensure you can't make that mistake.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply! You just made me realize my stupid mistake!

So, my code goes something like this:
`val friendList = result.data
liveData.postValue(friendList)
methodForNetworkCall2(friendList)`

Everything above is done in a coroutine on IO dispatcher, as well as the second method for network call, so things get done asynchronously, however when I am giving the friendList to the second method, I go through it and change "var" values inside of it, instead of adding it to a new list. Jesus! So much time wasted for this, haha! Thanks a lot!